# Erro em função criada

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Bom, fiz uma função, mas não está funcionando.
O objetivo dessa função é baixar um arquivo e quando terminar, retornar `true`.

Esta é a função:

```delphi
function TForm1.BaixarArquivo(Sender: TObject; Url:String; Name:Integer):Boolean;
var
  fileTD : TFileStream;
begin
  fileTD := TFileStream.Create(IntToStr(Name) + ExtractFileExt(Url), fmCreate);
  try
    Sender.Get(Url, FileTD);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(fileTD);
  end;
end;
```

Declarei assim no public:

```delphi
function BaixarArquivo(Sender: TObject; Url:string; Name:Integer): Boolean;
```

E chamei assim:

```delphi
BaixarArquivo(IdHTTP1, 'http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/5.rar', 5);
```

Mas retorna esse erro:

> [Error] LauncherUnit.pas(66): Undeclared identifier: 'Get'

Segunda função:

```delphi
function TForm1.RetornaPorcentagem(ValorMaximo, ValorAtual: Real):string;
var 
  resultado: Real;
begin
  resultado := ((ValorAtual * 100) / ValorMaximo); Result := FormatFloat('0%', resultado);
end;
```

O erro é do Floating division by Zero.

Comment: [O tópico que o @TiagoSilva falou é esse aqui.](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/846/sauda%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e-agradecimentos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema está no cast.

Sua função recebe um `TObject` e esse tipo de classe não possui um método Get.
Exatamente como diz a mensagem de erro:

> [Error] LauncherUnit.pas(66): Undeclared identifier: 'Get'

Veja: `Undeclared identifier: 'Get'.` Isso está dizendo que o método Get não é um identificador declarado.

Você precisa fazer um cast dentro do método:

```delphi
TIdHTTP(Sender).Get(Url, FileTD);
```

Ou melhor, já que é um método especializado para download de arquivos, declare pedindo um objeto do tipo TIdHTTP diretamente, assim:

```delphi
function BaixarArquivo(Sender: TIdHTTP; Url:string; Name:Integer): Boolean;
```

---

### Sobre o retorno da função

Você poderia fazer um teste verificando se o arquivo foi criado e então retornar o resultado do teste via `result`. Ficaria parecido com isso:

```delphi
function TForm1.BaixarArquivo(Sender: TIdHTTP; Url:String; Name:Integer):Boolean;
var
  fileTD : TFileStream;
begin
  fileTD := TFileStream.Create(IntToStr(Name) + ExtractFileExt(Url), fmCreate);
  try
    Sender.Get(Url, FileTD);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(fileTD);
  end;
  
  result := FileExists(IntToStr(Name) + ExtractFileExt(Url));
end;
```

---

### 3º Edit da pergunta, então 3ª adição de conteúdo na resposta

#### Questão:

Segunda função:

```delphi
function TForm1.RetornaPorcentagem(ValorMaximo, ValorAtual: Real):string;
var resultado: Real;
begin
  resultado := ((ValorAtual * 100) / ValorMaximo); Result := FormatFloat('0%', resultado);
end;
```

**O erro é do Floating division by Zero**.

As variáveis ValorAtual e/ou ValorMaximo estão recebendo o valor 0 (zero) em algum momento. Faça um teste dos valores antes de efetuar o cálculo.

Comment: Bom Tiago, tentei assim, agora retorna outro erro:
[Warning] LauncherUnit.pas(70): Return value of function 'TForm1.BaixarArquivo' might be undefined

Comment: Mas depois disso, o programa da crash.
'Process Launch.exe raised exception class EZeroDivide message 'Floating point division by zero'.

Comment: Bom, agora deu problema em uma função que eu já estava criada e funcionando. Editei no post.

Comment: Resolvido. Quanto meus erros, vou evita-los, não conheço muito as regras.